# Making div element background transparent to background image CSS

Tags: html, css, web, transparent

I would like to make a parallax effect within my website, however I am **unable to set the background of a DIV element to be transparent**, despite using `background-color: transparent`.

Essentially, I would like to solely display the text within a DIV, and remove the background color.

By using W3Schools..

```css
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .parallax {
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url('http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2013/Photoshop_Image_of_the_horse_053857_.jpg');
    
        /* Full height */
        height: 100%; 
    
        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .parallax2 {
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url('http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/114/4676052-image.png');
    
        /* Full height */
        height: 100%; 
    
        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    
    /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        .parallax {
            background-attachment: scroll;
        }
    }>
```

```html
    
    <div class="parallax"></div>
    
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:transparent;font-size:36px">
    Some text goes here, need to try to make the background of this transparent? Any ideas?
    </div>
    
    <div class="parallax2"></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: that div should stand within one of the container, else you have that 100px gap in between them. add a bg to body to find out .... https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QMWLGL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the background color to transparent you can do all of these.

`background-color: ;
 background-color: transparent;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

but in this case, you need to set a different position here is the code I hope this is what you were looking for

```
<div style="height:100px;font-size:36px; border:1px solid red; position: absolute;">
  Some text goes here, need to try to make the background of this transparent? Any ideas?
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems as though I had forgotten to set the position to absolute

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign a background-color to your div, it would be transparent automatically. That's the default. I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r26k8yke/) and tested it to make sure.

```
<div style="height:100px;font-size:36px; border:1px solid red;">
    Some text goes here, need to try to make the background of this transparent? Any ideas?
    </div>
```

If for any reason it didn't work, I would make a 2*2 transparent PNG in Photoshop and assign in as background-color, repeated in x and y directions both.

It's not a standard solution but will work surely. :D

Comment: That only worked as the first image was local, and was not present in that test. It still looks like this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6nc1d719/)

Comment: It doesn't have any background as far as I can see. Why do you think is has any background?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago.
You can easily write:

`background: none;`

or

`background: transparent;`

and then the element become transparent and the element under it will be visible.
But the text is still there.